# 20.04 Kill X Server With Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: 20.04, shortcuts, shortcut-keys

I recently bought a new computer, and had to install and reinstall Ubuntu once now because I'm lacking in technical knowledge sometimes, hence this post... After my last install, I found out, in no time at all with google and/or duckduckgo, how to, using the keyboard shortcuts app Ubuntu provides, kill the X Server session with ctrl+alt+bkspce .... Now I can't find the that information I got so quickly before to save my life (algorthihms musta changed), and I'm getting frustrated looking, only outdated info here so I figured it'd be worth an ask... thanks, and sorry if I missed another post or something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still possible, but should be configured manually.

To enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> open terminal and type:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> 5 times, then select `<Yes>` in the relevant window:

[image: enable Ctrl+Alt+Backspace]

and reboot.